# Hard to understand but general, French rules

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of French rules that are probably hard to understand that are not present yet on the site. Yes, we can find examples on other sites, but for someone using the French StackExchange, the answer is not there yet. I got in mind some examples like using *“plus d'un”*, or *“moins de deux”*, and so forth with weird or awesome rules and usages (*“Accord of some participe passés”* could also fit this).

I think we could produce great resources in the Q&A format that would be easier to understand for a lot of people. I personally prefer the Q&A format here from most of the other resources format available on the web. I find most of the other formats to be cluttered or not as clear.

I already know the answer to most of these since my native language is French, and thus I haven't asked them yet because I find it weird to post, since I already know the answer.

I was wondering should:

- I still post them and post at the same time an answer (and other people can contribute answers too)
- or should I post them as a Community Wikis? So everybody can edit it easily.
- or should I just not post it, since it's available on internet already?

As I said I think it would be great for the site to have these kind of *general* resources, but at the same time the answers are already widely on internet (even though sometimes it's in weird sites with ads or forums).

*If anything is unclear just ask for more information! I'd really like to see some discussion about that!*

---

**French**

Il y a beaucoup de règles qui sont dures à comprendre en français et qui ne sont pas discutées sur le site. Par exemple l'accord de *« plus d'un »* ou de *« moins de deux »*. Ces règles sont disponibles ailleurs sur le web, mais pas dans le format de Q&A du Stack Exchange. Parfois seulement disponible dans des forums, ou des sites remplis de publicité.

Je pense qu'on pourrait produire des ressources extrêmement utiles ici dans un format de style Q&A.

Je n'ai pas encore posé ces questions étant donné que ma langue maternelle est le français et je pense déjà connaître la plupart des règles et des utilisations de celles-ci.

Je me demandais :

- devrais-je les poser et proposer au même moment une réponse (et ensuite tout le monde peut aussi contribuer).
- Ou bien devrais-je les poser en mode Community Wiki pour que ce soit plus facile à modifier?
- Ou bien devrais-je m'abstenir étant donné que ces informations sont déjà disponibles ailleurs dans d'autres formats?

Answer (score 3):

It is always [OK to Ask and Answer your own questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Word of [God](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) says

> - if you have a question that you already know the answer to
> - if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
> - it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.
>
> To be crystal clear, **it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is *explicitly* encouraged**.

It would actually be great if you can provide good QAs in those areas. So, please, don't refrain yourself!

Comment: Voilà! I followed your advice! I hope that it will be useful for future people coming to the site!

Comment: I'll see if the question is well received and if it is, I might try producing other stuff like that. I think we could get a much better search engine visibility if we added questions about general, but edge/weird, French rules on the site, and produced good answers for them.